# logic to determine Dao calls based on logged in user and servlet called

Tags: java, servlets

I have three servlets

```
/Servelt1 (supervisors, managers & president can execute)
/Servelt2 (only managers & president can execute)
/Servelt3 (only president can execute)
```

each servlet uses Struts style actionMaps.  When each servlet is called with for example 
`?method=list` they all execute the Comment.getList()

```
/actionMap.put("list", new ListAction(modelMap, form, "WEB-INF/views/servlet1_v.jsp"));
/actionMap.put("list", new ListAction(modelMap, form, "WEB-INF/views/servlet2_v.jsp"));
/actionMap.put("list", new ListAction(modelMap, form, "WEB-INF/views/servlet3_v.jsp"));


Class Comment {  
//getList called from the 3 servlets
  public List<Comment> getList(HttpServletRequest request) {
     List<Comment> comments = null;
     try {
         CommentDetailDAO cdDao = new CommentDetailDAO();
    comments = cdDao.getComDetailListForDirectReports(authUser.getBadge());
    } catch (DAOException e) {
       setError(FORM_RESULTS, e.getMessage());
    }
    request.setAttribute("comments ", comments);
    return comments; //redundant not really used
  }
```

so what is to execute different Dao calls based on who is logged in and what servlet they are calling.

```
 if (supervisor) {
   comments = cdDao.getComDetailListForDirectReports(authUser.getBadge());
   //other dao calls 
 }
 if (manager & servlet1) {
   comments = cdDao.getComDetailListForDirectReportsAndTheirDirectReports(authUser.getBadge());
   //other dao calls
 }
 etc...
```

is the only way to use a lot of if/then/else logic?  Or should I have each servlet call a specific   SupervisorCommentClass.getList(), ManagerCommentClass.getList(), etc..?

==EDIT--
Over the weekend I though about this. Since I have a 3 distinct Servlets, and 3 distinct views for each of the servlets, it seems to make the most sense to have 3 distinct Class files containing business logic. So instead of each servlet calling `Comment.getList()` I think I should have 3 Comment classes:

```
SupervisorComment.getList();
ManagerComment.getList();
PresidentComment.getList();
```

Comment: Which frameworks you are using? or does it not matter?

Comment: If I write a code in the case, I use a dependency injection with custom annotations.

Comment: can you provide example code and post it as an Answer, not as a Comment

Answer (score 1):

It's just sample code I created now (and I didn't debug...): https://gist.github.com/4019608#comments

Comment: +1 for very verbose example code.  Let me study for a day or so. +1 for great effort

Comment: OK unfortunately work hasn't installed Java 7 so I don't have access to java.nio.file. BeanFactory is not compilable for me.  Will try to refactor backwards to Java 6

Comment: @jeff Why don't you try it yourself. I don't want to write a ancient language. I think you should create new another question about java7.

Comment: ahh sorry you miss read my comment, "Will try to refactor" meant I will try and refactor.  Java 6 Ancient, thats funny! When you work for large corporation, all software used is Ancient :)

Comment: Oh..I didn't understand. I should try to refactor my English skills.

Comment: ok so I got your sample code to work.  So I wasn't sure what was meant by dependency injection. After reviewing your working code, it seems like I am doing injection  new ListAction(modelMap, form, "WEB-INF/views/servlet1_v.jsp")); where form is the class with my business logic.  What I am doing now as mentioned in my edit above is creating new classes for Comment (SupervisorComment, ManagerComment), etc... maybe I can make base class and extend.